# How to refer to application properties within Config.groovy?

Tags: grails

Suppose in Config.groovy I specify my application property:

```
app.work.dir='/temp/work'
```

How can I refer to this property value to define other properties in the same Config.groovy file, i.e. this does not work because grailApplication.config has empty properties at this point:

```
app.resource.dir=grailsApplication.config.app.work.dir+'/static'
```

I know I can define a variable and then use this variable in both places, but it's really ugly, so I was hoping there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable substitution works in `Config.groovy`. Here's an example taken from some actual production code:

```
external.config.base = '/known/config/file/path'

grails.config.locations = ["file:${external.config.base}/myapp-config.groovy"]
sitemap.file.path = "${external.config.base}"
```

Comment: Right, once a variable is defined it's available, so you'd just use `app.resource.dir=app.work.dir+'/static'`

Comment: interestingly, this approach does not work if I declare the first property in another *.groovy file and load that config file by specifying it in grails.config.locations. This is because additional config files are loaded after Config.groovy